# What is the Mathematical proof of obtaining angles in getOrientation(float[] RotationMatrix, float[] orientationValue) android.hardware.SensorManager

Tags: android, android-sensors, rotational-matrices

**What values[] represent??**
What is the Mathematical proof for the same??

I found the definition of the   **public static float[] getOrientation(float[] R, float values[])** in android.hardware.SensorManager class as following.

```
public static float[] getOrientation(float[] R, float values[]) {
        /*
         * 4x4 (length=16) case:
         *   /  R[ 0]   R[ 1]   R[ 2]   0  \
         *   |  R[ 4]   R[ 5]   R[ 6]   0  |
         *   |  R[ 8]   R[ 9]   R[10]   0  |
         *   \      0       0       0   1  /
         *
         * 3x3 (length=9) case:
         *   /  R[ 0]   R[ 1]   R[ 2]  \
         *   |  R[ 3]   R[ 4]   R[ 5]  |
         *   \  R[ 6]   R[ 7]   R[ 8]  /
         *
         */
        if (R.length == 9) {
            values[0] = (float)Math.atan2(R[1], R[4]);
            values[1] = (float)Math.asin(-R[7]);
            values[2] = (float)Math.atan2(-R[6], R[8]);
        } else {
            values[0] = (float)Math.atan2(R[1], R[5]);
            values[1] = (float)Math.asin(-R[9]);
            values[2] = (float)Math.atan2(-R[8], R[10]);
        }
        return values;
    }
```

My Question is that if a vertex got rotation in degree z, y, & x in the respective Z, Y, & X Axis

the resultant matrix will be

```
RYX(y,x) = RY(y) * RX(x)
            _                _      _             _
           |Cy     0    Sy   0|    |1    0    0   0|
           |0      1    0    0|    |0    Cx  -Sx  0|
         = |-Sy    0    Cy   0|  * |0    Sx   Cx  0|
           |0      0    0    1|    |0    0    0   1|
           |_                _|    |_             _|

            _                               _
           |Cy      SySx          SyCx      0|
           |0       Cx            -Sx       0|
        =  |-Sy     CySx          CyCx      0|
           |0       0             0         1|
           |_                               _|


RZYX(z,y,x) = RZ(z) * RYX(y,x)
           _                _     _                               _
          |Cz    -Sz   0    0|   |Cy      SySx          SyCx      0|
          |Sz     Cz   0    0|   |0       Cx            -Sx       0|
        = |0      0    1    0|   |-Sy     CySx          CyCx      0|
          |0      0    0    1|   |0       0             0         1|
          |_                _|   |_                               _|            

           _                                         _
        = |CzCy     CzSySx-SzCx      CzSyCx+SzSx     0|
          |SzCy     SzSySx+CzCx      SzSyCx-CzSx     0|
          |-Sy      CySx             CyCx            0|
          |0        0                0               1|
          |_                                         _|
```

where Cx = cos(x), Cy = cos(y), Cz = cos(z), Sx = sin(x), Sy = sin(y) & Sz = sin(z)

according to function

```
values[0] = atan((CzSySx-SzCx)/(SzSySx+CzCx))
values[1] = asin(-CySx)
values[2] = atan(-Sy/CyCx)
```

**So are these values[] = {z, x, y} ?**

**If yes then give a mathematical proof for that**

**And if it is not representing x, y, z degree then what these values[] represent??**

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to quote the documentation

```
Computes the device's orientation based on the rotation matrix.

When it returns, the array values is filled with the result:

    values[0]: azimuth, rotation around the Z axis.
    values[1]: pitch, rotation around the X axis.
    values[2]: roll, rotation around the Y axis.

The reference coordinate-system used is different from the world coordinate-system defined for the rotation matrix:

    X is defined as the vector product Y.Z (It is tangential to the ground at the device's current location and roughly points West).
    Y is tangential to the ground at the device's current location and points towards the magnetic North Pole.
    Z points towards the center of the Earth and is perpendicular to the ground.

Inverted world coordinate-system diagram.

All three angles above are in radians and positive in the counter-clockwise direction.
```

Comment: My question remain same how atan2(R[1], R[5]) will give the rotation around the Z axis and for the same other Degree. In my question i have given a Rotation Matrix Could u give me a validation based on that??

Comment: Notice its using a different coordinate system than most of the other functions.  Z points directly to center of earth, not out the screen.

Comment: Is there any mathematical proof that  rotation around z axis = atan2(R[1], R[5])  and same other for rest two rotation around Y and X axis??